# NodeJS Bluez Ubuntu Dockerfile Error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

I have a docker file that is supposed to build a container to run a simple Bluetooth scanning program written with nodejs that depends on bluez, Ubuntu and Noble.js but when I run it I get the following error that stops me from building the container when running a `docker build -t`. Here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/UsersDoProgram/BlueScanner/blob/master/Dockerfile). And the error,

```
48 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
wget: invalid option -- 'f'
wget: invalid option -- 's'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     vim     python3     python3-dev     python3-pip     python3-virtualenv     python3-wheel     gcc     build-essential     libglib2.0-dev     libbluetooth-dev     libboost-python-dev     git     libdbus-1-dev     libudev-dev     libical-dev     libreadline-dev     wget     curl     --no-install-recommends &&     wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.49.tar.xz     tar -xf bluez-5.49.tar.xz     cd bluez-5.49     ./configure     make     make install     curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x -o nodesource_setup.sh     bash nodesource_setup.sh     apt-get update && apt-get install -y     apt-get install nodejs     ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following section, particularly where tar is first called:

```
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.49.tar.xz tar -xf bluez-5.49.tar.xz cd bluez-5.49 ./configure make make install curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x -o nodesource_setup.sh bash nodesource_setup.sh apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-get install nodejs ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

When executing multiple commands in succession on a single line, you need to separate those commands with an operator like `&&`.

- The `&&` operator will run a command, but only if the first succeeds
- The `||` operator will run a command, but only if the first fails
- The `;` operator will run a command, regardless if the first succeeds or fails

In addition you have a stray `apt-get install` in your command, most likely a copy/paste error. The section above should look like this:

```
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.49.tar.xz && tar -xf bluez-5.49.tar.xz && cd bluez-5.49 && ./configure && make && make install && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x -o nodesource_setup.sh && bash nodesource_setup.sh && apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs && ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

As an additional note, the `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` is probably unnecessary and will cause an error, as the nodejs package already appears to create `/usr/bin/node`.

Comment: I updated the [container](https://github.com/UsersDoProgram/BlueScanner/blob/master/Dockerfile) but when running the docker container, the container finishes irregularly, there is no output from the [main.js](https://github.com/UsersDoProgram/BlueScanner/blob/master/main.js) besides, "Got noble", from the file that is executed. When building the docker it said it successfully built but noble had a barrage of errors come up when attempting to install. The docker container isn't fully executing the node code like how it runs on a native system.

Comment: You can find the log [here](https://github.com/UsersDoProgram/BlueScanner/blob/master/log.txt) for the npm install noble part of the docker.

Comment: You're asking a separate question.